# Calculating accuracy gives wonky results

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a neural network that uses PyTorch. When I run it the accuracy seems a bit wonky (constant 1.00, see below).

epoch=20, loss=0.00002, val_loss=33.33334, acc=1.00000, val_acc=0.66667
.
.
epoch=70, loss=0.00000, val_loss=2.69771, acc=1.00000, val_acc=0.66667

Also val_acc doesn’t seem to change. Here’s my code I use to calculate accuracy:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    loss = n_correct = 0
    model3.train()
    for batch, target in train_loader:
        batch,target = batch.view(-1, n_metabolites).to(device),target.to(device)
        batch = batch.view(-1, n_metabolites).to(device)
        optimizer3.zero_grad()
        outputs = model3(batch)
        train_loss = objective3(outputs, target)
        loss += train_loss.item()
        n_correct += (target == (outputs.reshape(-1) > 0.5).float()).sum()
        train_loss.backward()
        optimizer3.step()
    
    loss = loss / len(train_loader)   
    acc = (n_correct.float() / len(train)).cpu().numpy()
    epoch += 1
        
    model3.eval();
    val_loss = val_n_correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch, target in val_loader:
            batch,target = batch.view(-1, n_metabolites).to(device),target.to(device)
            batch = batch.view(-1, n_metabolites).to(device)
            outputs = model3(batch)
            val_loss += objective3(outputs, target)
            val_n_correct += (target == (outputs.reshape(-1) > 0.5).float()).sum()
        val_loss = (val_loss / len(val_loader)).cpu().numpy()
        val_acc = (val_n_correct.float() / len(val)).cpu().numpy()

    
    if (epoch % print_stats_interval) == 0 or epoch == epochs:
        print(f'epoch={epoch:.0f}, loss={loss:.5f}, val_loss={val_loss:.5f}, acc={acc:.5f}, val_acc={val_acc:.5f}')
    log3.append((epoch, loss, val_loss, acc, val_acc))
log3 = pd.DataFrame(log3, columns=['epoch', 'loss', 'val_loss', 'acc', 'val_acc'])
```

Where am I going wrong in calculating the accuracy?

Comment: Your calculation method seems correct, did you consider the possibility of your model overfitting?

Comment: I didn't consider that, but that might be the case! Thank you.